# select a row based on different column value (same row)

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(c("WTN", "KON", "WTH","KOH"), each = 3),
                 Time = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 4),
                 replicate(3,sample(1:100,12,rep=TRUE)))
```

I want to select a row based on the values of two different columns of the same row, in this case "WTN" and "A". Expected output:

```
1  WTN    A 84 96 26
```

Comment: It is not clear about the logic.  Also, please use `set.seed` to make this reproducible

Comment: `df[df$ID == "WTN" & df$Time == "A", ]` is this it?

Comment: @joel.wilson kudos for not answering this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `filter` from `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
     filter(ID == "WTN" & Time == "A")
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I use this approach to subset just columns with values?

Comment: @Al14  You can add `%>% select(-ID)` if I understand your question

Comment: Am I going to need a second line after filter?

Comment: @Al14  Perhaps `df %>% filter(ID == "WTN" & Time == "A") %>% select(-ID, -Time)  %>% unlist(., use.names = FALSE)`